# Get element in binary search tree given a path of ones and zeros

Tags: binary-search-tree

I have a string of ones and zeros, zero mean left and ones mean right, and I need to        return the item to the end of the path. If the path leads to nothing returns null.

Tree:

```
      15
     /  \
    12  18
   /   /  \
 10  16  20
  \   \
   11  17
```

- String 001 will return  11
- String 101 will return  17
- String 1111 will return  null

How can I write this method in Java?

Comment: you forgot to mention a minor detail: which programming language...

Comment: further, SO is for people who try to help themselves while you give the impression of someone who's like other people to do his homework...

Answer (score 0):

you can traverse among this tree and check for each character of the string if it is 0 then getleft() and if it is 1 then getright()

and so on, i hope this help :D

i have a midterm tomorrow so i don't have time to write it's implementation now :D

Comment: Thanks I figured it out.